# SOLVED Restored a tar of a physical CentOS machine to a vm and now it won't boot

Tags: linux, centos, virtual-machines, centos5, backup-restoration

I have a physical CentOS 5.11 machine and I created a tar of it using:

```
sudo su
cd /
tar cvpzf backup.tgz --exclude=/proc --exclude=/lost+found --exclude=/backup.tgz --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/sys /
```

I created a Hyper-V virtual machine, installed CentOS 5.11 and restored the backup using:

```
 tar xvpfz backup.tgz -C /
```

Now the machine won't boot.  This is the screen I'm confronted with upon boot:
(sorry, I can't post images yet) https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZZ6h.jpg

I've tried all sorts of reinstalling grub both from a CentOS recovery image and from third party disk recovery images, mkinitrd and so many other things that I can't even remember.  I've hit a wall here. Does anyone know why this is happening and how I might fix it?  Thanks.

Edit: I've posted the contents of grub.conf, menu.lst, fstab and lvdisplay in the comments.  I'm unable to post them here as I don't have enough rep points.

Edit 2:
I solved this issue!  Thanks to everyone in the comments for your assistance.  It was seriously appreciated.

To resolve the problem I booted into a Fedora live cd and mounted my file systems as I mentioned in the comments.  Once mounted I issued the following: `mkinitrd --with=hid-base-hv --with=hid-hyperv --with=hv_utils --with=hv_vmbus --with=hv_storvsc --with=hv_netvsc /boot/initrd-2.6.18-408.el5.img 2.6.18-408.el5 -f` Then I rebooted the machine and it came alive.

Comment: can you add your grub.conf, boot/grub/menu.lst and /etc/fstab? It seems like there is a missing label or option mismatch? Did the physical have the same kernel as the VM?

Comment: Plus add your LVM info.

Comment: @Tux_DEV_NULL

I booted to a Fedora live cd and followed up to step 5 from here to mount the drive: [link](https://goo.gl/kxj5x4)

When I look in /etc this is what I see for grub.conf
[grublink](https://imgur.com/a/dFc7N)
And here's the contents of grub.conf
[grub contents](https://imgur.com/a/pFcy9)
Here is the contents of boot/grub/menu.lst
[menu.lst](https://imgur.com/a/p1CfJ)
And here is the contents of /etc/fstab
[fstab](https://imgur.com/a/dXRyt)

I'm researching how to answer the kernel question you asked. Thanks for the help

Comment: @fuero Here is the contents of lvdisplay.  If you were referring to anything different please let me know.
[lvdisplay](https://imgur.com/a/rkAtQ)

Comment: @Tux_DEV_NULL I run a "uname -r" on my physical and get 2.6.18-408.e15 but I can't do that from my vm as it's running off of a live image and it just keeps bringing back Fedora info.  If I cat /etc/redhat-release I get CentOS release 5.11 (Final) on both machines.

Comment: It looks like it can't find your volume group, which makes me wonder if the kernel has the right module for accessing the disk exposed by Hyper-V. In Hyper-V, how is your disk image configured? Plain IDE/SATA or SCSI should be used.

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack I booted to a Fedora live cd then 'mkdir /mnt/sysimage' and '/mnt/sysimage/boot'.  Then 'mount /dev/VolGroup00/LogVol00 /mnt/sysimage' and 'mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/sysimage/boot'.  After that 'mount --bind /dev /mnt/sysimage/dev', 
'mount --bind /proc /mnt/sysimage/proc' and 
'mount --bind /sys /mnt/sysimage/sys'.  Finally 'chroot /mnt/sysimage'

Comment: Sorry, new question. See above. Also `backticks` are your `friends` in comments :)

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack Sorry for the quote mess.  I fixed it up.  In Hyper-V, the disk is connected to an IDE Controller.

Comment: Ok, let's assume the kernel can see the disk. Perhaps the kernel thinks the vg is foreign because of a systemid mismatch. Try clearing the systemid: Boot up with a live cd and issue: `vgchange --systemid "" VolGroup00`. There's no need to mount your filesystems

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack I rebooted to a live cd and issued `vgchange --systemid "" VolGroup00` and received Empty system ID Supplied.  Volume Group system ID is already ""

Comment: @AlastairMcCormack I started investigating the kernel module thing you mentioned earlier.  I did a `uname -r` on the physical and got 2.6.18-408.e15.  On my vm I issued mkinitrd as in [this image](https://imgur.com/a/CpIVi) and got the no modules message.

Edit: wait a second..I was using 1 when it should be l..

Comment: I think disk duplication `dd` will be more quickly than the time will spent  for LVM recovery. You had deleted the new `/etc/lvm/lvm.conf` file by rewriting the old one.

Comment: @MikhailKhirgiy I understand `dd` should probably be used on an unmounted disk and that's my problem.  I couldn't shutdown my machine for that long.

Comment: @TheKoolestIP Then you need to move only those data what is really needed for your services.